# Trouble trying to use multiple rendertargetviews and viewports at the same time

Tags: hlsl, viewport, geometry-shader, rendertargets

I have worked on the GSCubemap demo for DX11 to obtain rendering to multiple rendertargets and modified it to render to a single RTV with multiple viewports with SV_ViewportArrayIndex. I'm now trying to mix the two is it possible? I'm facing a vertex-pixel shader linkage error (SV_RTVArrayIndex and SV_VPArrayIndex required for input and not provided by output stage.

Here's the code summarized

```
struct VS_INPUT {some VSData}
struct GS_INPUT {some GSData}
struct PS_INPUT
{
    some PSData;
    uint RTIndex:SV_RenderTargetArrayIndex;
    uint VPIndex:SV_ViewportArrayIndex;
} 

GS_INPUT VSShader(VS_INPUT) {Calcul GS_INPUT;return it}

[maxvertextexcount 15] //5 VPs, 1 for RTV0, 4 for RTV1
void GSShader (triangle GS_INPUT input[3], inout trianglestream<PS_INPUT>, outstream)
{
   PS_INPUT output;
   output.RTVIndex = 0;
   output.VPIndex =0;
   for (v =0 to 3 v++) {output.Data = input.data;outstream.append(output);}
   outstream.restartstrip();
   output.RTVIndex = 1;
   for vp=1;v<5;vp++
    {
       output.VPIndex =vp;
       for (v =0 to 3 v++) {output.Data = input.data;outstream.append(output);}
       outstream.restartstrip();
    }
 }

 float4 PSShader(PS_INPUT input): SV_TARGET
{ return input.Color; }
```

Currently I see the content of the RTV0 only.
I have also tried with an output PS structure having float4 Color0/1 SV_TARGET0/1 but there's a problem with the COLOR semantics mismatched on the hardware.

Comment: I have forgotten to set the vertex format at GS shader creation. Now I see the viewport effect but it it only at the first target (VP1/VP2 draws overlapp bigger VP0).